# Algorithm for converting truth tables to Boolean functions

Tags: implementation-details, boolean-computation

The function `BooleanFunction` is able to convert a truth table into a Boolean function.

Does anyone know what is the mathematical background and/or algorithm that underlies this particular application of `BooleanFunction`?